# Generate NULL stubs for all undefined symbols in unittest in a portable manor

Tags: c, macos, unit-testing, linker, ld

## What I'm Trying to Do

I am trying to enhance a simple unit testing framework for C code that I have written. It works very well with the exception of one annoying quirk: the test for any given function must contain stubs for all symbols defined in the source file that contains the function under test even if the function under test does not use those symbols. Here is a simplified example to illustrate what I mean:

source.c:

```c
extern int some_function(void);
extern void another_function(int a);
extern int some_variable;

int foo(void)
{
    int x = some_function();
    return x + some_variable;
}

int bar(void)
{
    another_function(7);
    return 1;
}
```

unittests/bar_test.c:

```c
#include "source.c"

// Stubs
void another_function(int)
{
    // Validate arguments somehow here
}

// Tests
int main (void)
{
    int result = another_function();
    if (result == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

There would be a separate file, `foo_test.c`, to test the `foo()` function.

The problem I am facing is that I can't link the test for `bar()` as written above because it does not contain stubs for `some_function` or `some_variable`. Those symbols will never be used in the test, so I don't really care that they are missing and would like to find a way to push the problem of actually needing to have all of those symbols defined off until the symbols are actually used so that I don't need to write a large number of stubs that will never be called.

I have been trying to find a way to either define all the undefined symbols as `NULL` at link time or to create a separate object file with all of the missing symbols I need defined as `NULL` so that the linker will be happy but if the symbols are actually used a runtime I will get a segfault.

A requirement that is causing me a lot of trouble here is that I would greatly prefer that this worked both on Linux with the GNU linker and with the macOS linker, but as you will see in the next section the macOS linker is missing a number of features that would make this easier for me.

## What I've Tried So Far

### Using `-defsym`

I am able to get a list of the undefined symbols in my test object file using `nm -u`, from this list I can add a `-defsym=symbol_name=0x0` for each of the symbols that I need to define to my linker command. This almost works, but unfortunately there are a couple of problems.

- I have not been able to find a way to list only symbols in the object which are both undefined and not present in libc (ie. symbols which will still be undefined after dynamic linking)
- The macOS linker does not have a `-defsym` argument or, as far as I can tell, any equivalent

### Using a linker script

Similar to the method above, I can generate a linker script to define all of the symbols that are not defined in my test object file as 0x0 and use the script when linking my test. This has the same two problems:

- Same as above, I end up defining symbols from dynamically linked libraries (libc) as 0x0
- The macOS linker does not appear to support linker scripts

### Using a Separate Object File

I have tried using both of the above methods both directly as part of the linking process for my test and by first creating a separate `stubs.o` and linking with that. The separate object file doesn't seem to help.

## A Quick Summary

My goal is to be able to link and run a unit test even if it contains undefined symbols and have the test crash at runtime if it encounters a missing stub. I would like this to work on Linux using gcc and the gnu linker and on macOS with clang and the macOS linker (ld64). I am hoping that someone might now how I can:

- Identify the undefined symbols in my test object file that need to be stubbed out
- Define those symbols as NULL at link time in a portable way

Comment: It seems to me that you need to use the list of public symbols from the linked libraries to exclude them from being redefined as NULL.

Comment: I solved a similar problem by writing small sources providing all potentially referenced objects, and then build a library of these. Linking that library includes any otherwise undefined object, satisfying the linker, but keeps the option to provide needed mock-ups in the test driver.